# UserControl tab focus not working

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, tabs, onfocus

I got a class that extends UserControl

I have a few tabs in it, and I want to recognise when a tab is selected, so I have this:

```
     this.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(OnGotFocus);

     private void OnGotFocus(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                if (DataContext != null)
                {
                    ((SomeViewModelClass)DataContext).SetActiveTab();
                }
            }
```

So my problem is: when I select a tab for the first time, the OnGotFocus mehod is called, however when I select some other tabs, and come back and select it a second time, it doesn't get called for some reason, any one know why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are using WPF's Tab Control Right?

Why are you doing `this.GotFocus....`? what is `this` exactly in this case?

You should do something like this if you want `GetFocus` to be called when a `Tab` is selected.

XAML (sample Tabs)

```
  <TabControl>
            <TabItem x:Name="table1"></TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="table2"></TabItem>
            <TabItem></TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Code Behind

```
//register event for each individual tab

table1.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(table1_GotFocus);
table2.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(table2_GotFocus);

private void table1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}

private void table2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

let me know if I misunderstood you requirement